zoom in not working only able to zoom out works but in console the zoom values are correct but not visible on screen
Zoom is not working only zoom out is working i wanted the canvas to fit the viewport maybe something related to that not sure
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Image Cropper</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css">
    <style>
        body,
        html {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background: black;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            flex-direction: column;
        }

        .controls {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            pointer-events: none;
            /* Allows clicks to pass through */
        }

        .controls button,
        .controls select {
            pointer-events: auto;
            /* Re-enable pointer events for controls */
            background-color: black; /* Set button background to black */
            color: white; /* Set text color to white */
        }

        .top-right {
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            right: 10px;
        }

        .top-left {
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            left: 10px;
        }

        .bottom-left {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 10px;
            left: 10px;
        }

        .bottom-right {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 10px;
            right: 10px;
        }

        .image-container-wrapper {
            /* width: 80%; */
            /* height: 80%; */
            max-width: 90vw;
            max-height: 90vh;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            overflow: visible;
            /* Important to make sure that anything beyond the bounds is hidden */
        }

        .image-container {
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        canvas {
            width: 100%;
            /* Might restrict enlargement depending on parent's fixed dimensions */
            height: 100%;
            display: block;
        }

        .overlay {
            position: absolute;
            border: 2px solid yellow;
            cursor: move;
            touch-action: none;
            z-index: 1;
        }

        .corner {
            position: absolute;
            width: 15px;
            height: 15px;
            background-color: yellow;
            border-radius: 50%;
        }

        .corner.top-left {
            top: -7.5px;
            left: -7.5px;
        }

        .corner.top-right {
            top: -7.5px;
            right: -7.5px;
        }

        .corner.bottom-left {
            bottom: -7.5px;
            left: -7.5px;
        }

        .corner.bottom-right {
            bottom: -7.5px;
            right: -7.5px;
        }

        .overlay-background {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            pointer-events: none;
        }
    </style> </head>

<body>
    <div class="controls">
        <select id="shapeSelect" onchange="selectShape()" class="top-left">
            <option value="rectangle" selected>Rectangle</option>
            <option value="circle">Circle</option>
        </select>
        <button id="cropButton" class="top-right">Crop</button>
        <div class="bottom-left">
            <button onclick="rotateImage(-90)"><i class="fas fa-undo"></i></button>
            <button onclick="rotateImage(90)"><i class="fas fa-redo"></i></button>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom-right">
            <button onclick="zoomImage(1.2)"><i class="fas fa-search-plus"></i></button>
            <button onclick="zoomImage(0.8)"><i class="fas fa-search-minus"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="image-container-wrapper">
        <div class="image-container">
            <div class="overlay-background"></div>
            <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
            <div class="overlay">
                <div class="corner top-left"></div>
                <div class="corner top-right"></div>
                <div class="corner bottom-left"></div>
                <div class="corner bottom-right"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- <div id="croppedImagePreview"></div> -->

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui-touch-punch/0.2.3/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            const imageObj = new Image();
            const overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay');
            const overlayBackground = document.querySelector('.overlay-background');
            let selectedShape = "rectangle";
            let angle = 0;
            let zoomFactor = 1;  // Initial zoom factor

            imageObj.onload = function () {
                drawRotatedImage();
            };

            imageObj.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
            imageObj.src = 'rope41.png'; // Update image URL

            window.selectShape = function () {
                selectedShape = document.getElementById("shapeSelect").value;
                overlay.style.borderRadius = selectedShape === "circle" ? "50%" : "0%";
            };

            window.rotateImage = function (deg) {
                angle = (angle + deg) % 360;
                drawRotatedImage();
                // This should be done after redrawing the image and possibly resizing the overlay.
                setTimeout(function () {
                    initializeOverlay();
                }, 100); // Delay might be needed for the DOM updates to settle
            }

            window.zoomImage = function (factor) {
                zoomFactor *= factor;
                console.log("Zoom Factor: " + zoomFactor);
                drawRotatedImage();
            }

            function drawRotatedImage() {
                const radians = angle * Math.PI / 180;
                const sin = Math.abs(Math.sin(radians));
                const cos = Math.abs(Math.cos(radians));

                const imageWidth = cos * imageObj.width + sin * imageObj.height;
                const imageHeight = sin * imageObj.width + cos * imageObj.height;

                const scaleX = (window.innerWidth / imageWidth) * zoomFactor;
                const scaleY = (window.innerHeight / imageHeight) * zoomFactor;
                const scaleToFit = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);

                console.log("Canvas dimensions: " + canvas.width + " x " + canvas.height);

                const canvasWidth = imageWidth * scaleToFit;
                const canvasHeight = imageHeight * scaleToFit;

                canvas.width = canvasWidth;
                canvas.height = canvasHeight;

                ctx.setTransform(scaleToFit, 0, 0, scaleToFit, canvasWidth / 2, canvasHeight / 2);
                ctx.rotate(radians);
                ctx.drawImage(imageObj, -imageObj.width / 2, -imageObj.height / 2);

                ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);

                initializeOverlay();
            }


            function initializeOverlay() {
                const containerRect = document.querySelector('.image-container-wrapper').getBoundingClientRect();
                overlay.style.width = `${containerRect.width - 4}px`;
                overlay.style.height = `${containerRect.height - 4}px`;
                overlay.style.top = '0px';
                overlay.style.left = '0px';

                setupOverlayInteractions(containerRect.width - 4, containerRect.height - 4);
            }

            function setupOverlayInteractions(width, height) {
                if ($.data(overlay, 'ui-resizable')) {
                    $(overlay).resizable('destroy');
                }
                if ($.data(overlay, 'ui-draggable')) {
                    $(overlay).draggable('destroy');
                }

                // Set up resizable
                $(overlay).resizable({
                    containment: "parent",
                    handles: 'n, e, s, w, ne, se, sw, nw',
                    minWidth: 50,
                    minHeight: 50,
                    resize: function (event, ui) {
                        updateOverlayBackground(ui.position, ui.size);
                    }
                });

                // Set up draggable
                $(overlay).draggable({
                    containment: "parent",
                    drag: function (event, ui) {
                        updateOverlayBackground(ui.position, { width: ui.helper.width(), height: ui.helper.height() });
                    }
                });

                updateOverlayBackground({ top: '0px', left: '0px' }, { width, height });
            }

            function updateOverlayBackground(position, size) {
                const left = parseFloat(position.left) || 0;
                const top = parseFloat(position.top) || 0;
                const width = parseFloat(size.width) || 0;
                const height = parseFloat(size.height) || 0;

                overlayBackground.style.clipPath = `polygon(
                    0 0, 
                    0 100%, 
                    ${left}px 100%, 
                    ${left}px ${top}px, 
                    ${left + width}px ${top}px, 
                    ${left + width}px ${top + height}px, 
                    ${left}px ${top + height}px, 
                    ${left}px 100%, 
                    100% 100%, 
                    100% 0
                )`;
            }

            document.getElementById('cropButton').addEventListener('click', function () {
                const canvasRect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
                const bounds = overlay.getBoundingClientRect();

                const scaleX = canvas.width / canvasRect.width;
                const scaleY = canvas.height / canvasRect.height;

                const cropX = (bounds.left - canvasRect.left) * scaleX;
                const cropY = (bounds.top - canvasRect.top) * scaleY;
                const cropWidth = bounds.width * scaleX;
                const cropHeight = bounds.height * scaleY;

                const croppedCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                const croppedCtx = croppedCanvas.getContext("2d");
                croppedCanvas.width = cropWidth;
                croppedCanvas.height = cropHeight;

                croppedCtx.drawImage(canvas, cropX, cropY, cropWidth, cropHeight, 0, 0, cropWidth, cropHeight);

                // const imgPreview = document.getElementById('croppedImagePreview');
                // imgPreview.innerHTML = '';
                const img = new Image();
                img.src = croppedCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                console.log("Base64", img.src);
                // imgPreview.appendChild(img);
            });
        });
    </script> </body>

</html>

